# Debug assembly prints limited amount of characters

Tags: assembly, x86, dosbox

I have been working on project with DOS Debug. I have to take string and count symbol's 0, 2, 3 and 6 bit sum. If it is even, I need to turn that symbol into 4. And I have to print out string backwards. I have done almost everything.

But I have a problem and I stuck. It only prints out 12 characters. Where the problem could be?

Input:  abcdefghijklmn

Output: n4lk4i4g4e44

Expected output: n4lk4i4g4e44b4 (more, than 12 characters)

This is the code

```
a800
db 50 00

a100
mov ah, 09
mov dx, 700
int 21
mov ah, 3f
mov dx, 800
int 21

a150
mov bx, 800
mov si, 0
jmp 250

a250
mov al, [bx+si]
mov cl, [bx+si]
mov byte [750], cl
cmp al, 20
jl 490
mov ah, 0
clc
rcr al, 1
adc ah, 0
clc
rcr al, 2
adc ah, 0
clc
rcr al, 1
adc ah, 0
clc
rcr al, 4
adc ah, 0
mov al, ah
mov ah, 0
clc
rcr al, 1
adc ah, 0
cmp ah, 0
jg 300
jmp 320

a300
mov byte [bx+si], 34
inc si
jmp 250

a320
mov byte [bx+si], [750]
inc si
jmp 250

a490
mov byte [bx+si+1], 24
xor dx, dx
jmp 500

a500
mov ah, 02
mov dl, [bx+si]
int 21
dec si
loop 500
mov ah, 4c
int 21

a700
db "Iveskite teksta " 0A 0D "$"

n bb.com
r cx
1000
w
q
```

**a250 counts bit's sum**

**a490 adds $ sign to the end**

EDIT: I think that loop stops working after twelve reps.

Comment: `mov byte [bx+si], [750]` <-- What is that supposed to do? Did you mean to write `mov byte [bx+si], 750`? (which would be strange since 750 doesn't fit in a byte).

Comment: int21/3f expects a count in `cx` (and also a file handle in `bx` which you accidentally seem to have working but should set explicitly).

Comment: Your description is also a bit vague. Please show the input you're testing with, as well as the expected and actual outputs.

Comment: Oh, that is my bad. I put one char in [750], so I could put that back in it's place. I fixed that one with putting [750] in register, and then in it's place. Thank you

Comment: I updated the info about input and output.

Comment: Where do you set up the loop count (i.e. `cx`) for `loop 500` ?

Comment: I tried to do that with SI. I am using SI as a counter. It counts, how many characters there are.

Comment: The `loop` instruction has no idea that you're using `si` as a counter. It always uses `cx` (or `ecx` or `rcx`).

Comment: In the `a100` chunk after the second `int 21` you are missing a jump.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is simpler than expected. Thanks to @Jester and @Michael comments. I had a bad loop. I just moved si to cx and it works perfectly. Thank you all for help.

```
a490
mov byte [bx+si+1], 24
xor cx, cx
mov cx, si
inc cx
jmp 500

a500
mov ah, 02
mov dl, [bx+si]
int 21
dec si
loop 500
mov ah, 4c
int 21
```

Comment: You don't need to zero CX with XOR before `mov cx, si`.  `mov` overwrites the destination regardless of the old value.  Also, this is still really over-complicated; you're already counting down `si` toward zero, just use it as the loop counter instead of the `loop` instruction.  No need to use extra instructions for CX.  e.g. `dec si` / `jge 500` like the bottom of a `do{}while(--si >= 0)`.  (Using `jge` instead of `jnz` solves the off-by-one problem you're avoiding here with `inc cx`.)

Comment: Only use the `loop` instruction when it actually *saves* instructions, as a code-size optimization.  And then only if you don't care about speed on modern Intel CPUs: [Why is the loop instruction slow? Couldn't Intel have implemented it efficiently?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35742570)